# Unable to install packages in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: python, svm, google-cloud-datalab

I have been trying to insatll 'svmutil' on Google Datalab using the following command -

```
 %bash

 pip install svmutil
```

I am getting the following error -

```
Collecting svmutil
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement svmutil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for svmutil
```

​What can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The svmutil package does not appear to exist on PyPi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svmutil

Is this a local package?  If so you'll need to pass the path of the library tarball into pip instead of just the name.

Comment: How is it done? I am new to these concepts , so I am not aware.